# Vue Draggable move to previous list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, sortables

I am using [vue js draggable plugin](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable?ref=madewithvuejs.com)

It was working fine with single list but i need to work with multiple lists ( like Jira board ). I want to move a card ( element ) from one list to another but it should work with a post request. If i get a negative response from server then i should be able to move it back to the previous state.

Things i have done so far includes using

**:move** :

it works if i have to reject a move directly without using ajax call.

**@change** :

I am not able to revert using this method. This is actually the one i want to work with.

Comment: Remember the element before the move, if ajax fails, move it back to first list

Comment: Or maybe this [github issue](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/347#issuecomment-363476203) can help